# BBatch Error - Error reading data from bbatch

Tags: algorithm, math, set, software-design

I am getting an error when I am opening the **Atelier B tool**. Below is the error message.

> "Please check that the resource file exists and that you are using a
>   correct bbatch version."

Error message

> Resource file: file or
>   directory C:\Users\ASUS i5\AtelierB_Data\AtelierB_free_4.5.1\press\bdb
>   does not exist or cannot be accessed

Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This worked for me!!!**

Click **Show Details**...

[image]

Then you will see an error message saying that you don't have the resource file in a particular directory.

[image]

**Solution**

In my case, the directory is **C:\Users\ASUS i5** go inside and

1. Create a new folder and named it to **'AtelierB_Data'**
2. Then inside that folder create another new folder and named it to
   **'AtelierB_free_4.5.1'**
3. Go to your Atelier B installation folder and copy **'press'** folder and paste it inside the **'AtelierB_free_4.5.1'**

That's all (Y)

**Note-**

*Replace 1,2,3 according to your error message.